# Split rows to columns in R

Tags: r, reshape, melt

I have a text data file like this (with multiple rows for respective category [A,B,C]):

```
A=1,2,3,6,
7,9
10
B=3,4,5
C=5,7,8,10,11,
13,14
```

When I load to R it becomes a data frame with 6 obs. and 1 variable

```
df <- read.delim("file.text",header = FALSE)

    v1
1   A=1,2,3,6,
2   7,9
3   10
4   B=3,4,5
5   C=5,7,8,10,11,
6   13,14
```

How can I change to this format?

```
   A  B  C
1  A
2  A
3  A  B
4     B
5     B  C
6  A
7  A     C
8        C
9  A
10 A     C
11       C
13       C
14       C
```

Thanks!

Comment: You won't find a built-in function for this. You'll have to import the file as a string and then write a function to parse it using regex

Comment: CHONG, let us know how the answers below worked out for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic approach would be to read the data in as a string, split on `=` and `,`, and then figure out the best way to identify which group each number belongs with.

In the following approach, I've intentionally used type conversion to create the groups. Since this will involve coercion from character to numeric, since there are characters in the split values, expect several warning messages.

```
# Load the data.table package.
library(data.table)

# Read in the data.
x <- fread("A=1,2,3,6,
7,9
10
B=3,4,5
C=5,7,8,10,11,
13,14", sep = "\n", header = FALSE)

x[, unlist(strsplit(V1, "=|,"), use.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE), .I][
  , list(ind = as.integer(V1), col = rep(V1[1], .N)), cumsum(is.na(as.integer(V1)))][
    , dcast(na.omit(.SD), ind ~ col, value.var = "col", fill = "")]
#     ind A B C
#  1:   1 A    
#  2:   2 A    
#  3:   3 A B  
#  4:   4   B  
#  5:   5   B C
#  6:   6 A    
#  7:   7 A   C
#  8:   8     C
#  9:   9 A    
# 10:  10 A   C
# 11:  11     C
# 12:  13     C
# 13:  14     C
```

Here's another alternative using `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package. "x" is the same data read in using `fread`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(
  cSplit(x[, toString(V1), cumsum(grepl("[A-Z]", V1))], "V1", "="), "V1_2", ",", "long")[
    , dcast(.SD, V1_2 ~ V1_1, value.var = "V1_1", fill = "")]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  #Remove commas at the end of the string
  mutate(V1 = sub(",$", "", V1)) %>%
  #Divide data into separate column based on "=" sign
  separate(V1, into = c("let", "num"), sep = "=", fill = "left") %>%
  #fill the NA values with it's respective group
  fill(let) %>%
  #Convert comma-separated value into different rows
  separate_rows(num, convert = TRUE) %>%
  #Convert data to wide format filling missing values with empty string
  pivot_wider(names_from = let, values_from = let, values_fill = list(let = "")) %>%
  #Arrange data according to numbers
  arrange(num)

#  # A tibble: 13 x 4
#     num A     B     C    
#   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 A     ""    ""   
# 2     2 A     ""    ""   
# 3     3 A     B     ""   
# 4     4 ""    B     ""   
# 5     5 ""    B     C    
# 6     6 A     ""    ""   
# 7     7 A     ""    C    
# 8     8 ""    ""    C    
# 9     9 A     ""    ""   
#10    10 A     ""    C    
#11    11 ""    ""    C    
#12    13 ""    ""    C    
#13    14 ""    ""    C
```

If you want `num` column as rownames add `%>% column_to_rownames('num')`.

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "A=1,2,3,6,
7,9
10
B=3,4,5
C=5,7,8,10,11,
13,14")
```

Comment: I think you should stop at `arrange(num)` to get the correct answer.

Comment: Ok, kept the `num` column for clarity.

Comment: Cool. +1. `column_to_rownames('num')` is also an appropriate solution, but removing "num" didn't since it would indicate that there was a `C=12` in the data (which there isn't).

Answer (score 1):

A base R approach using `readLines()`. We first store cell indexes starting with characters in a vector `ch`, which helps to find sequences to `paste` together into `l2`. `l2` `as.numeric` already gives the indexes for the final data frame `d`. We construct `d` out of `NA`s from the dimensions of `l3` and fill it up according to the values of `l3`.

```
l <- readLines("delim.txt")
ch <- c(grep("^\\D", l))
l2 <- apply(rbind(ch, c(ch[-1] - 1, length(l))), 2, 
            function(x) Reduce(paste, l[x[1]:x[2]]))
l3 <- lapply(sapply(strsplit(l2, "\\D"), as.numeric), na.omit)
d <- matrix(NA, max(sapply(l3, max)), length(l3))
let <- gsub("(.*)\\=.*", "\\1", l2)  # the col-names
sapply(seq(length(l3)), function(n) d[l3[[n]], n] <<- let[n])
setNames(as.data.frame(d), let)
#      A    B    C
# 1     A <NA> <NA>
# 2     A <NA> <NA>
# 3     A    B <NA>
# 4  <NA>    B <NA>
# 5  <NA>    B    C
# 6     A <NA> <NA>
# 7     A <NA>    C
# 8  <NA> <NA>    C
# 9     A <NA> <NA>
# 10    A <NA>    C
# 11 <NA> <NA>    C
# 12 <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 13 <NA> <NA>    C
# 14 <NA> <NA>    C
```

Answer (score 1):

In *base* you can `paste` the lines to one line, use `strsplit` to get the single numbers and the columnname, create a named `matrix` and fill it by using subset.

```
x <- readLines(con=textConnection("A=1,2,3,6,
7,9
10
B=3,4,5
C=5,7,8,10,11,
13,14"))

x <- paste(gsub("=","",x), collapse = ",")
y <- lapply(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(x, "[[:alpha:]]+"))[-1], ","), function(i) i[!i==""])
names(y)  <- strsplit(x, "[^[:alpha:]]+")[[1]]
z <- sort(unique(as.numeric(unlist(y))))
res <- matrix("", nrow=length(z), ncol=length(y), dimnames=list(z, names(y)))
sapply(names(y), function(i) res[y[[i]], i]  <<- i)
res
#   A   B   C  
#1  "A" ""  "" 
#2  "A" ""  "" 
#3  "A" "B" "" 
#4  ""  "B" "" 
#5  ""  "B" "C"
#6  "A" ""  "" 
#7  "A" ""  "C"
#8  ""  ""  "C"
#9  "A" ""  "" 
#10 "A" ""  "C"
#11 ""  ""  "C"
#13 ""  ""  "C"
#14 ""  ""  "C"
```